# Dealing with redux state after user cancels a call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, axios

For a example a user goes to a page, but quickly goes back to another page - I use the AbortController from axios to abort the calls from the previous page to not slow down the app.

My question is - now that I've aborted the call - what do I do with the state?
For example FAQ's were starting to load, so the react state is iLoading: true,
after aborting - it will continue being isLoading: true
even thought the user is not on the page I do not think this is correct, how should I proceed with the state? I also cannot call a FAILURE action because there is no error that has happened?

I've created an AbortController class that handles and keeps track of each call and on path change I cancel any ongoing requests.

Comment: what stops you from calling the `FAILURE` action?  Is it that you need an instance of `Error` to construct a `yourEvent.FAILURE(...)`?  Or is it that your reducer will then place your state in an "error" state and you don't want that?  Or something else?

Comment: Provide the code of how you managed your loading. Is it a global loading state ? If so there are better ways to manage loading. Also you can use `tanstack-query`  to manage your api calls and their loading/error states and also abort them if necessary. Search about it, It's pretty handy.

Answer (score 0):

> I use the AbortController from axios to abort the calls from the previous page to not slow down the app

Have you measured the exact performance impact of doing this? Because I'd bet it is negligible. There is no such thing as truly "aborting" a request, all axios can do is ignore the response when it arrives (it's like ordering something online - once the package is on its way, there is no way to stop it in transit. you can only discard it once you get it).

Browsers limit the number of concurrent requests to a single domain. So it's possible that if axios calls https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort under the hood, your browser actually could send one more request in that moment. But I'd verify if that is actually the case in your app. And weigh this against the complexity you're introducing. A lot of optimization is premature.

But to answer your question:

> what do I do with the state?

If you have explicit request lifecycle states like `pending`, `fulfilled`, and `rejected` (like https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk ), you would have to introduce a fourth one (e.g. `idle` or `initial`) and dispatch an action that resets the state for this type of request.

> I've created an AbortController class that handles and keeps track of each call and on path change I cancel any ongoing requests.

Same concern here - it's nice if this works, but can you quantify how much it actually helps? Does it shave 200ms off the page load time if you navigate to "FAQ" and quickly click another client side route? What if it's only 10ms and now you're carrying the burden of maintaining an AbortController class and every request through redux has 4 states instead of 3.